# The multi-part identifier could not be bound sql error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have taken over the support of an Excel 2010 macro and need to change the sort order of a recordset.

The query below worked before I attempted to change the order by adding `rl.list_order`.

Now I'm getting the error `"The multi-part identifier could not be bound"` and have tried many alternatives and have researched on this site for a solution but haven't been able to solve this.  Can someone please help.

```
SELECT ips_rc.project, lfbe.Category, ips_rc.roster_id, ips_rc.role_category, ips_rc.role_title AS Role, ips_rc.role_code, ips_rc.role_title + ' (' + ips_rc.role_code + ')' AS PS_Role, CASE WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code, '')  = '' THEN 'TO_BE_MAPPED' ELSE ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code, '') END AS Pronto_Role_Code, CASE WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description, '')  = '' THEN ips_rc.role_title ELSE ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description, '') END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Description, ISNULL(lfbe.Rate, 0) AS Rate, CASE WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Old, '')  = '' THEN ips_rc.role_title ELSE lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Old END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Old, CASE WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old, '') = '' THEN 'TO_BE_MAPPED' ELSE lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old, ips_rc.Shift, ips_rc.UOM, ips_rc.Date, ips_rc.DHours, ips_rc.NHours FROM (SELECT psrc.project, pr_jcm.customer, pr_jcm.subcode, psrc.roster_id, psrc.role_id, psrc.role_category, psrc.role_title, 
    psrc.role_code, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN psrc.Date BETWEEN psrc.start_date AND psrc.end_date THEN psrc.NWorkHours ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY psrc.project, psrc.roster_id) >= SUM(CASE WHEN psrc.Date BETWEEN psrc.start_date AND psrc.end_date THEN psrc.DWorkHours ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY psrc.project, psrc.roster_id) THEN 'Night Shifts' ELSE 'Day Shifts' END AS Shift, 'HOURS' AS UOM, psrc.Date, psrc.DHours, psrc.NHours FROM (SELECT rcd.project, rcd.start_date, rcd.end_date, rcd.roster_id, rcd.role1_id AS role_id, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test1.category WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test2.category WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test3.category ELSE rcd.role_category END AS role_category, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test1.title WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test2.title WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test3.title ELSE rcd.role_title END AS role_title, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test1.band_r
    ole_id AS VARCHAR) WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test2.band_role_id AS VARCHAR) WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test3.band_role_id AS VARCHAR) ELSE rcd.role_code END AS role_code, rcd.shift_date AS Date, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS DHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day' AND rcd.shift_type = 'work' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS DWorkHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day' AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqmob' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS DEqmobHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day' AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqdemob' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS DEqdemobHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS NHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night' AND rcd.shift_type = 'work' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS NWorkHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night' AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqmob' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS NEqmobHours, SUM(CASE WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night' AND rcd.sh
    ift_type = 'eqdemob' THEN rcd.shift_time ELSE 0 END) AS NEqdemobHours FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT p.job_no AS project, p.start_date, p.end_date, rs.roster_id, IFNULL(rs.role_id, 0) AS role1_id, IFNULL(r.role2_id, 0) AS role2_id, IFNULL(r.role3_id, 0) AS role3_id, rl.category AS role_category, rl.title AS role_title, rl.role_code AS role_code, rs.shift_date, rs.shift_ampm, rs.shift_time, rs.shift_type, s.client_id FROM lfmanage.t_roster_shift rs JOIN lfmanage.t_project AS p ON p.project_id = rs.project_id LEFT JOIN lfmanage.t_site AS s ON s.site_id = p.site_id JOIN lfmanage.t_roster AS r ON r.roster_id = rs.roster_id JOIN lfmanage.t_role AS rl ON rl.role_id = rs.role_id WHERE p.job_no = ''700704'' AND CASE WHEN ISNULL(rs.deleted) THEN 0 ELSE rs.deleted END = 0') AS rcd LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT client_id, band_role_id, title, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title),'SUPER') > 0 THEN 'super' ELSE 'trade' END AS category, role1_id, role2_id, role3_id FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_r
    ole_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id, brs.role3_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role2_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role3_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id, brs.role3_id')) AS rb_test1 ON rb_test1.client_id = rcd.client_id AND rb_test1.role1_id = rcd.role1_id AND rb_test1.role2_id = rcd.role2_id AND rb_test1.role3_id = rcd.role3_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT client_id, band_role_id, title, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title),'SUPER') > 0 THEN 'super' ELSE 'trade' END AS category, role1_id, role2_id FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_role_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role2_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id '
    )) AS rb_test2 ON rb_test2.client_id = rcd.client_id AND rb_test2.role1_id = rcd.role1_id AND rb_test2.role2_id = rcd.role2_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT client_id, band_role_id, title, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title),'SUPER') > 0 THEN 'super' ELSE 'trade' END AS category, role1_id, role3_id FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_role_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role3_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role3_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role3_id ')) AS rb_test3 ON rb_test3.client_id = rcd.client_id AND rb_test3.role1_id = rcd.role1_id AND rb_test3.role3_id = rcd.role3_id WHERE rcd.shift_date > '2017-01-01' GROUP BY rcd.project, rcd.start_date, rcd.end_date, rcd.roster_id, rcd.role1_id, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test1.category WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test2.category WHEN rb_test3.role
    1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test3.category ELSE rcd.role_category END, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test1.title WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test2.title WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN rb_test3.title ELSE rcd.role_title END, CASE WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test1.band_role_id AS VARCHAR) WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test2.band_role_id AS VARCHAR) WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(rb_test3.band_role_id AS VARCHAR) ELSE rcd.role_code END, rcd.shift_date) AS psrc INNER JOIN (SELECT job_no AS project, Client AS customer, '3700002213' AS subcode FROM [dbo].[vw_PlanningSystem_Projects] WHERE job_no = '700704') AS pr_jcm ON pr_jcm.project = psrc.project) AS ips_rc LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rates.Client, rates.SubCode, mapping.Category, mapping.Shift, mapping.IPS_Role_Code, rates.Pronto_Role_Code, rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Description, rates.Rate, rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Old, rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old FROM (SELECT UPPER(Ca
    tegory) AS Category, 'Day Shifts' AS Shift, IPS_Role_Code, Day_Cost_Code As Pronto_Role_Code FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_RoleCode_MasterMapping] UNION ALL SELECT UPPER(Category) AS Category, 'Night Shifts' AS Shift, IPS_Role_Code, Night_Cost_Code As Pronto_Role_Code FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_RoleCode_MasterMapping]) AS mapping INNER JOIN (SELECT Client, SubCode, CASE WHEN Shift = 'Day Shift' THEN 'Day Shifts' WHEN Shift = 'Night Shift' THEN 'Night Shifts' Else '' END AS Shift, Pronto_Role_Code, Pronto_Role_Code_Description, Rate, Pronto_Role_Code_Old, Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_SubCodes_Rates]) AS rates ON rates.Shift = mapping.Shift AND rates.Pronto_Role_Code = mapping.Pronto_Role_Code) AS lfbe ON lfbe.Client = ips_rc.customer AND lfbe.SubCode = ips_rc.subCode AND lfbe.Shift = ips_rc.Shift AND lfbe.IPS_Role_Code = ips_rc.role_code ORDER BY ips_rc.project ASC, ips_rc.role_title ASC, rl.list_order
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The issue is related to alias.You assign an alias to a table like this  `select a.col1,a.col2 from tbl a`.Now in this query ,i can use `a.col1` ,if i try to use `b.col1` sql will complain the error you are getting.Try checking to see where you have alias  mismatch.

Comment: Further you can't refer aliases like this `select b.col1 from (select * from tbl b) a`.Hope this gives you some idea on where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the formatting, you've got a lot going on here... Stack Overflow veterans, I'm just starting to dip my toes in here, so if this isn't correct, give me some grace.

In your first OPENQUERY statement, I don't see `rl.list_order` as a field being returned.  If that's a column you're trying to ORDER BY, I think you should be able to add `rl.list_order` to your SELECT list within that statement which you alias as `rcd`.

Since that's within a nested sub-query, you'll want to elevate it to each of the calling queries.  I think it's something like this...  Try it out and post back with any errors.

```
  SELECT ips_rc.ListOrder
    , ips_rc.project
    , lfbe.Category
    , ips_rc.roster_id
    , ips_rc.role_category
    , ips_rc.role_title AS [ROLE]
    , ips_rc.role_code
    , ips_rc.role_title + ' (' + ips_rc.role_code + ')' AS PS_Role
    , CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code, '') = ''
            THEN 'TO_BE_MAPPED'
            ELSE ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code, '')
        END AS Pronto_Role_Code
    , CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description, '') = ''
            THEN ips_rc.role_title
        ELSE ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description, '')
        END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Description
    , ISNULL(lfbe.Rate, 0) AS Rate
    , CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Old, '') = ''
            THEN ips_rc.role_title
        ELSE lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Old
        END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Old
        , CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old, '') = ''
            THEN 'TO_BE_MAPPED'
        ELSE lfbe.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old
        END AS Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old
        , ips_rc.Shift
        , ips_rc.UOM
        , ips_rc.DATE
        , ips_rc.DHours
        , ips_rc.NHours
FROM (
    SELECT psrc.ListOrder -- Added
    , psrc.project
    , pr_jcm.customer
    , pr_jcm.subcode
    , psrc.roster_id
    , psrc.role_id
    , psrc.role_category
    , psrc.role_title
    , psrc.role_code

    , CASE 
            WHEN SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN psrc.DATE BETWEEN psrc.start_date
                                AND psrc.end_date
                            THEN psrc.NWorkHours
                        ELSE 0
                        END) OVER (PARTITION BY psrc.project, psrc.roster_id) >= SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN psrc.DATE BETWEEN psrc.start_date
                                AND psrc.end_date
                            THEN psrc.DWorkHours
                        ELSE 0
                        END) OVER (PARTITION BY psrc.project, psrc.roster_id)
                THEN 'Night Shifts'
            ELSE 'Day Shifts'
            END AS Shift, 'HOURS' AS UOM, psrc.DATE, psrc.DHours, psrc.NHours
    FROM (
        SELECT rcd.list_order --Added
            , rcd.project
            , rcd.start_date
            , rcd.end_date
            , rcd.roster_id
            , rcd.role1_id AS role_id
            , CASE 
                    WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test1.category
                    WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test2.category
                    WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test3.category
                    ELSE rcd.role_category
            END AS role_category
            , CASE 
                    WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test1.title
                    WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test2.title
                    WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test3.title
                    ELSE rcd.role_title
                    END AS role_title
                    , CASE 
                    WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN CAST(rb_test1.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                    WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN CAST(rb_test2.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                    WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN CAST(rb_test3.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                    ELSE rcd.role_code
                    END AS role_code, rcd.shift_date AS DATE
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day'
                        THEN rcd.shift_time
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS DHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'work'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS DWorkHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqmob'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS DEqmobHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'day'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqdemob'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS DEqdemobHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'work'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NWorkHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqmob'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NEqmobHours
            , SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN rcd.shift_ampm = 'night'
                            AND rcd.shift_type = 'eqdemob'
                            THEN rcd.shift_time
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NEqdemobHours
        FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT p.job_no AS project, p.start_date, p.end_date, rs.roster_id, IFNULL(rs.role_id, 0) AS role1_id, IFNULL(r.role2_id, 0) AS role2_id, IFNULL(r.role3_id, 0) AS role3_id, rl,ListOrder, rl.category AS role_category, rl.title AS role_title, rl.role_code AS role_code, rs.shift_date, rs.shift_ampm, rs.shift_time, rs.shift_type, s.client_id FROM lfmanage.t_roster_shift rs JOIN lfmanage.t_project AS p ON p.project_id = rs.project_id LEFT JOIN lfmanage.t_site AS s ON s.site_id = p.site_id JOIN lfmanage.t_roster AS r ON r.roster_id = rs.roster_id JOIN lfmanage.t_role AS rl ON rl.role_id = rs.role_id WHERE p.job_no = ''700704'' AND CASE WHEN ISNULL(rs.deleted) THEN 0 ELSE rs.deleted END = 0') AS rcd --Added
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT client_id
                    , band_role_id
                    , title
                    , CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title), 'SUPER') > 0
                                THEN 'super'
                            ELSE 'trade'
                            END AS category
                    , role1_id
                    , role2_id
                    , role3_id
                    FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_role_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id, brs.role3_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role2_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role3_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id, brs.role3_id')
                ) AS rb_test1
                ON rb_test1.client_id = rcd.client_id
                    AND rb_test1.role1_id = rcd.role1_id
                    AND rb_test1.role2_id = rcd.role2_id
                    AND rb_test1.role3_id = rcd.role3_id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT client_id, band_role_id, title, CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title), 'SUPER') > 0
                        THEN 'super'
                    ELSE 'trade'
                    END AS category, role1_id, role2_id
            FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_role_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role2_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role2_id ')
            ) AS rb_test2
                ON rb_test2.client_id = rcd.client_id
                    AND rb_test2.role1_id = rcd.role1_id
                    AND rb_test2.role2_id = rcd.role2_id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT client_id, band_role_id, title, CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(UPPER(title), 'SUPER') > 0
                        THEN 'super'
                    ELSE 'trade'
                    END AS category, role1_id, role3_id
            FROM OPENQUERY([LFMANAGE], 'SELECT br.client_id, MIN(brs.band_role_id) AS band_role_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role3_id FROM t_band_role_set AS brs INNER JOIN t_band_role AS br ON br.band_role_id = brs.band_role_id WHERE IFNULL(brs.role1_id, 0) <> 0 AND IFNULL(brs.role3_id, 0) <> 0 GROUP BY br.client_id, br.title, brs.role1_id, brs.role3_id ')
            ) AS rb_test3
                ON rb_test3.client_id = rcd.client_id
                    AND rb_test3.role1_id = rcd.role1_id
                    AND rb_test3.role3_id = rcd.role3_id
        WHERE rcd.shift_date > '2017-01-01'
        GROUP BY rcd.list_order --Added 
            , rcd.project
            , rcd.start_date
            , rcd.end_date
            , rcd.roster_id
            , rcd.role1_id
            , CASE 
                WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN rb_test1.category
                WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test2.category
                    WHEN rb_test3.ROLE1_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN rb_test3.category
                    ELSE rcd.role_category
                END
            , CASE 
                WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN rb_test1.title
                WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN rb_test2.title
                WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN rb_test3.title
                ELSE rcd.role_title
                END
            , CASE 
                WHEN rb_test1.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN CAST(rb_test1.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                WHEN rb_test2.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN CAST(rb_test2.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                WHEN rb_test3.role1_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN CAST(rb_test3.band_role_id AS VARCHAR)
                ELSE rcd.role_code
                END
            , rcd.shift_date
        ) AS psrc
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT job_no AS project
                    , Client AS customer
                    , '3700002213' AS subcode
                FROM [dbo].[vw_PlanningSystem_Projects]
                WHERE job_no = '700704'
                ) AS pr_jcm
                    ON pr_jcm.project = psrc.project
    ) AS ips_rc
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT rates.Client
                , rates.SubCode
                , mapping.Category
                , mapping.Shift
                , mapping.IPS_Role_Code
                , rates.Pronto_Role_Code
                , rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Description
                , rates.Rate
                , rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Old
                , rates.Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old
            FROM (
                    SELECT UPPER(Category) AS Category
                        , 'Day Shifts' AS Shift
                        , IPS_Role_Code
                        , Day_Cost_Code AS Pronto_Role_Code
                    FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_RoleCode_MasterMapping]

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT UPPER(Category) AS Category
                        , 'Night Shifts' AS Shift
                        , IPS_Role_Code
                        , Night_Cost_Code AS Pronto_Role_Code
                    FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_RoleCode_MasterMapping]
                    ) AS mapping
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Client
                , SubCode
                , CASE 
                    WHEN Shift = 'Day Shift'
                        THEN 'Day Shifts'
                    WHEN Shift = 'Night Shift'
                        THEN 'Night Shifts'
                    ELSE ''
                    END AS Shift
                , Pronto_Role_Code
                , Pronto_Role_Code_Description
                , Rate
                , Pronto_Role_Code_Old
                , Pronto_Role_Code_Description_Old
            FROM [LFBudgetEstimate].[dbo].[LFBE_SubCodes_Rates]
            ) AS rates
            ON rates.Shift = mapping.Shift
                AND rates.Pronto_Role_Code = mapping.Pronto_Role_Code
        ) AS lfbe
            ON lfbe.Client = ips_rc.customer
                AND lfbe.SubCode = ips_rc.subCode
                AND lfbe.Shift = ips_rc.Shift
                AND lfbe.IPS_Role_Code = ips_rc.role_code
ORDER BY ips_rc.project ASC, ips_rc.role_title ASC, ips_rc.list_order ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right CSharp821 there's an awful lot going on there.  I made the changes you suggested and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access alias `rl`, however the `rl` alias is only visible within the `OPENQUERY` which has an alias of `rcd`. Try order by `rcd.list_order` instead of `rl.list_order`